# object become null when updating value

Tags: reactjs, forms, crud

I'm building a CRUD application of some articles. Now i'm working on Edit functionnality, when i click on Edit button, all data of specific article are populated in the form.

This is the structure of article data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 109,
        "code": "code1",
        "article": "article1",
        "price": "6.000",
        "vat": {
            "id": 99,
            "vat": "0.111",
            "company_id": 42
        },
        "status": 0,
        "company_id": 42
    }
]
```

As you can see, `vat` is an **`object`** inside an **`array of objects`**. Vat is a document that linked to article collection by it's `id`.

Good, everything is ok till now, back to my question.

Now after i make an edit on my data (update code to "code2") and hit update button, data of updated article become like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 109,
        "code": "code2",
        "article": "article1",
        "price": "6.000",
        "vat": null,
        "status": 0,
        "company_id": 42
    }
]
```

Why vat become null?

My code:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import React from 'react'
import propTypes from 'prop-types'
import {
  CButton,
  CForm,
  CFormInput,
  CFormSelect,
  CModal,
  CModalBody,
  CModalFooter,
  CModalHeader,
  CModalTitle,
} from '@coreui/react'
import { getUsers, editUser } from '../Service/api'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { getVats } from 'src/Service/apiVat'

export default function DialogEditArticle(props) {
  /* console.log(props.data) */
  //...
  const [ViewEdit, setEditShow] = useState(false)
  const [id, setId] = useState('')
  const [code, setCode] = useState('')
  const [article, setArticle] = useState('')
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(null)
  const [vat, setVat] = useState(null)
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(null)
  const [articleData, setArticleData] = useState([id, code, article, price, vat, status])
  const [vatselect, setVatSelect] = useState([])

  const normalize = (v) => ({
    code: String(v.code),
    article: String(v.article),
    price: Number(v.price),
    vat: Number(v.vat),
    status: Number(v.status),
  })

  const handleEditShow = () => {
    setEditShow(true)
  }
  const handleEditClose = () => {
    setEditShow(false)
  }

  const handleEdit = () => {
    editUser(props.data, normalize(articleData)).then(() => props.getAllUsers())
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadArticleDetails = async () => {
      const response = await getUsers(id)
      setArticleData(response.data.find((x) => x.id === props.data))
    }
    loadArticleDetails()
  }, [props.data, id])

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadvatsdetails = async () => {
      const response = await getVats()
      setVatSelect(response.data)
    }
    loadvatsdetails()
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <CButton
        style={{
          marginRight: '10px',
          color: 'info',
          border: 'none',
          boxShadow: `2px 2px 9px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6)`,
        }}
        onClick={() => handleEditShow(setId(props.data.id))}
      >
        Edit
      </CButton>
      <CModal
        visible={ViewEdit}
        onClose={handleEditClose}
        backdrop={'static'}
        keyboard={false}
        portal={false}
        scrollable
      >
        <CModalHeader>
          <CModalTitle>Edit Article:</CModalTitle>
        </CModalHeader>
        <CModalBody>
          <CForm>
            <CFormInput
              type="text"
              id="exampleFormControlInput1"
              label="Code :"
              placeholder="Enter Code"
              text=" "
              aria-describedby="exampleFormControlInputHelpInline"
              name="code"
              onChange={(e) => setCode(e.target.value)}
              defaultValue={articleData.code}
            />
            <CFormInput
              type="text"
              id="exampleFormControlInput2"
              label="Article :"
              placeholder="Enter Article"
              text=" "
              aria-describedby="exampleFormControlInputHelpInline"
              name="article"
              onChange={(e) => setArticle(e.target.value)}
              defaultValue={articleData.article}
            />
            <CFormInput
              type="number"
              id="exampleFormControlInput3"
              label="Price :"
              placeholder="Enter Price"
              text="Must be a number"
              aria-describedby="exampleFormControlInputHelpInline"
              name="price"
              onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)}
              defaultValue={articleData.price}
            />
            <CFormSelect
              onChange={(e) => setVat(e.target.value)}
              label="VAT :"
              aria-label="vat select"
              name="vat"
              value={vat}
            >
              <option selected disabled value={''}>
                -- select an option --
              </option>
              {vatselect.map((v) => (
                <option key={v.id} value={v.id}>
                  {v.vat}
                </option>
              ))}
            </CFormSelect>
            <CFormInput
              type="text"
              id="exampleFormControlInput5"
              label="Status :"
              placeholder="Enter Status"
              text=" "
              aria-describedby="exampleFormControlInputHelpInline"
              name="status"
              onChange={(e) => setStatus(e.target.value)}
              defaultValue={articleData.status}
            />
          </CForm>
        </CModalBody>
        <CModalFooter>
          <CButton color="secondary" onClick={() => setEditShow(false)}>
            Cancel
          </CButton>
          <CButton
            color="primary"
            onClick={() => {
              handleEdit()
              setEditShow(false)
            }}
          >
            Update
          </CButton>
        </CModalFooter>
      </CModal>
    </>
  )
}

DialogEditArticle.propTypes = {
  getAllUsers: propTypes.func,
  data: propTypes.any,
}
```

Comment: You are trying to convert `vat` to number instead of an object at `normalize` function.

Comment: can you tell me what should i put instead of `Number` in Normalise function?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve at `normalize`?

Comment: By `normalize`, i'm trying to define the type of each data (code, article, price..etc)

Comment: My question was rather why do you need “to define the type”? And why do you convert ‘vat’ which is originally represents an object to number?